# Lookup column missing from document properties list

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, word, template

For the scope of this question I am working with SharePoint 2013.

I have a Tasks list that was created with the OOTB (add an app) Task list.

I have a Document Library that was created with the OOTB (add an app) Document Library.

In the document library I added a column that was the type of "Lookup".  I selected the tasks list and in this column I have "Task Name".  I also included "% Complete" and "Due Date".  The fields do show up as columns in the document library.

I then go in to the Advanced Settings for the document library and edit the template. Then I go to the Insert Tab and when I select Document Properties those fields such as "% Complete" and "Due Date" do not show up.  The initial "Task Name" is available and I am able to select the actual task; however, these additional properties are not available for the document.  What can I do to have these fields show up in the document such that when the "% Complete" is updated in that Tasks list that it will also be updated in the viewable document?

Essentially I am doing what is described here, the only difference is that I am using a lookup column instead of external content http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/use-external-data-columns-in-a-word-document-HA102847511.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to allow users to modify the look up item (Task Item) from the document itself?  if that is the case I do not believe you can do that.  You can only select a Task to associate to the document.

Comment: Ya it is a little disappointing.  You would think that any of the fields that you see in the document library would be able to be added as fields to the document template but I guess not.  I also noticed that I am unable to add Hyperlink / Picture types of data as properties.